# PHP wait for a post.

Tags: php, post

I know that PHP is not asynchronous. Functions are executed one after another.

What I want to do is a post, then process the info and call procedures based on the post info.
For instance multiple choice. if its "a" then process(a) if its "b" then process(b).

So what are the possible things I can use to accomplish this?

JavaScript? 
Ajax? 
Perl?
Can someone point me to some examples?

Thank You

Comment: Do a post from what (your script? a browser?) to what (your script? A third party URI?)?

Comment: Can you be a bit more elaborate on how you'd like this to work. I envision a "wizard" format: process and complete step 1, move to 2, then on to 3, etc.

Comment: Are you making a PHP script that _makes_ this POST (via cURL or similar) or _receives_ the POST from a user?

Comment: Are you looking for [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)s?

Comment: No this is a simple program. Ask the user a question. Get the answer with post. Then ask more questions based on the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your point, juste switch between post values!

```
<?php

$action = htmlentities($_POST['action']);

switch ($action) {
   case 'a':
     handle_a();break
   case 'b':
     handle_b();break
   default:
     menu();
}
```

If you have php > 5.3 (which is not my case so I couln't test that piece of code), you can also use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/fr/functions.anonymous.php):

```
<?php

$action = $_GET['action'];
$available_actions = array('a' => function () { echo "handling a"; },
                           'b' => function () { echo "handling b"; });
if (array_key_exists($action, $available_actions))
{
        $available_actions[$action]();
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you running `htmlentities` over that?

Comment: Well my first attempt was to print out that value.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // do stuff in there like add the switch
}
```

this will only run if the post has been submitted, then you could add Alf's switch statement to switch between other posted items and do different things.

Comment: But when I call the procedure, it contains another post and the var is set from previous.

Comment: Its fine if I only ask one question. But when I ask follow up questions, the var is already set. Even if the var is a local in a procedure.